# MySql Select with Combined Index Using Wrong Index

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbname`.`test_table` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,      
  `confidence` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `check_status` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `createdAt` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modifiedAt` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   INDEX task_status (task_id, check_status),
   INDEX task_name_conf(task_id, name, confidence))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 11
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

I have the following queries that are used pretty often:

```
select * from test_table where task_id = 13 and check_status = 1;
select name from test_table
    where task_id = 13
    AND name like '%name%'
        order by confidence desc;
```

As you can see, I created the 2 index to accelerate the above queries. When I do a `explain` on the second query, although `task_status` and `task_name_conf` are both listed as `possible_keys`, the `key` field only has `task_status`. The `ref` field only has a `const` as well, which means it's only using `task_id` here.

Why is it not using `task_name_conf` index to execute the 2nd query?

Edit:

I got it that name **like** and then order by cannot take advantage of this index.  Only equals can work. `name ='name' order by confidence` utilized the `task_name_conf` index. But the weird thing is `select name from test_table where task_id= and name= and confidence=` (standard 3 equals) failed to use index `task_name_conf` again.

Comment: I got it that `name like` and then order by cannot take advantage of this index. `name ='' order by confidence` utilized `task_name_conf` index. But the weird thing is `select name from test_table where task_id= and name= and confidence=` (standard 3 equals) failed to use index `task_name_conf` again.

Comment: Server made the decision based on cardinality. How many unique values in the name column? Have you analyzed table after adding the task_name_conf index (it might take some time for server to analyze it automatically). I believe it must be used as it is covering index and in fact my local instance of MySQL (5.7) show it as it would be used in case name = 'name'

Comment: @fifonik That makes sense.  I think it's due to my test data, I'm not randomizing it enough.  The analyze thing might also be a cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name like '%name%'` condition cannot use any index because the value you are looking for can be anywhere within the field.

The `confidence` field is the last in the `task_name_conf` index with the `name` field before it, so the optimiser cannot use this index to order by the `confidence` either.

This means that only `task_id` field is covered by any of the indexes, so mysql chooses the smaller (less fields) index.

Either you need to leve the `name` field out of the second index completely. Or if the name search is the most expensive criterion, then condider using a fulltext index and search instead of a simple psttern matching.

Comment: Actually even `explain select name
    from test_table
    where task_id = 13
    AND name = 'name' and confidence=1; ` only uses `task_id`. I cannot find a case where it uses all of them.

Comment: `explain select name
    from test_table
    where task_id = 13
    AND name like 'name%'
        order by confidence desc;`  or  `explain select name
    from test_table
    where task_id = 13
    AND name = 'name'
        order by confidence desc;` only uses `task_id` as well.

Comment: In that case mysql thinks that the selectivity of the other two fields are so low, that it is not worth using the second index. If you disagree then use `force index` in your query. But only use this if there is a significant performance gain. Otherwise let mysql have its way.